# java button opening mysql connection not working

Tags: java, event-handling

I am trying to execute a query through a button click but I seem to have something wrong.

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {


    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

        try {
            String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fabius";
            String uName = "x";
            String uPass = "x";

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String SQL = "SELECT * from prices";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

            System.out.println(rs);
        }
        catch (SQLException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }

    }
});
```

This returns the error

`no suitable driver found`

Comment: You forgot to add the driver...

Comment: add mysql driver to classpath

Comment: would you mind showing me an example please?

Comment: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

Comment: I do not know where to add it to my existing code.

Comment: Follow the tutuorial at this link: http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/

Comment: sorry, but I have no idea where I am going wrong.

Comment: Before creating a connection instance, you need to load the Driver class. So as suggested by @NewBee Developer, add Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); Also, make sure that you are executing the program with mysql-connector jar in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this works as required.

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {



    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
       try{
       String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fabius";
       String uName = "root";
       String uPass = "cupcup";
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

       Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
       String SQL = "SELECT `HGM.L` from prices";
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);


       rs.next();
       System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));

       }

       catch (SQLException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }


    }
});
```